# Скрипт для переноса строк на новый лист

Tags: excel, vba

Ни как не удается заставить работать скрипт для созданиях "неразрывных подписей". Это такой диапазон строк, которые при печати должны находится на одном листе.

У меня есть книга, в ней несколько листов, в листах есть диапазоны следующего типа:

- Podpis0
- Podpis1
- Podpis2
- и т.д.

Мне нужно написать скрипт, который будет автоматически перебирать все диапазоны и ставить переносы в нужных местах.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)
  ActiveSheet.ResetAllPageBreaks

  For Each Nm In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    If Left(Nm, 6) = "Podpis" Then
      Dim R As Range
      Set R = Range(Nm)
      Set R = R.Offset(-1, 0).Resize(R.Rows.Count + 1, R.Columns.Count)
      R.Rows.PageBreak = xlPageBreakNone
      For Each Rw In R.Rows
        If Rw.PageBreak = xlPageBreakAutomatic Then
          R.Rows.PageBreak = xlPageBreakManual
        End If
      Next
    End If
  Next Nm
End Sub
```

Получилось что-то такое. Но он, почему то не работает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В местах, где надо было использовать имя диапазона (`Left(Nm, 6)` и `Range(Nm)`) нужно было просто использовать `Nm.Name`.